# Document.ready not working when using grunt server

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have those scripts in my index.html for testing grunt build web app, but I found that, it actually not running the function when DOM ready, if in a normal way to run this index.html, it works, but in grunt, it not, is there any potentials problems may cause it?

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.button_1').click(function() {
                $(".voltage").show();
                $(".current").hide();
                $(".button_2").hide();
                });
            $('.button_2').click(function() {
                $(".voltage").hide();
                $(".current").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

PS. I have jquery.js loaded before running it.

Comment: Any console errors? I wonder if the $ namespace is conflicting. Maybe try `jQuery(function($) {});`.

Comment: What do you mean about run the index.html in grunt ?